# Illegal instruction. 0x00007ffff3712210 in nsync::nsync_mu_init(nsync::nsync_mu_s_*) while loading libtensorflow_cc.so

Tags: tensorflow2.0, illegal-instruction

A part of my application uses tensorflow to load the model. Application code is compiled with tensorflow2.3 using devtoolset-7.
While trying to run my application binary it crashes while loading libtensorflow_cc.so with stack trace

```
Illegal instruction.
0x00007ffff3712210 in nsync::nsync_mu_init(nsync::nsync_mu_s_*)


12:56
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00007ffff3712210 in nsync::nsync_mu_init(nsync::nsync_mu_s_*) ()
   from /lib64/libtensorflow_cc.so.2
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install controller-1.0.0-20201014_19_13_07.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff3712210 in nsync::nsync_mu_init(nsync::nsync_mu_s_*) ()
   from /lib64/libtensorflow_cc.so.2
#1  0x00007fffea72df4e in tensorflow::monitoring::Gauge<bool, 0>::Gauge(tensorflow::monitoring::Met
ricDef<(tensorflow::monitoring::MetricKind)0, bool, 0> const&) ()
   from /lib64/libtensorflow_cc.so.2
#2  0x00007fffea72e1f4 in tensorflow::monitoring::Gauge<bool, 0>* tensorflow::monitoring::Gauge<boo
l, 0>::New<char const (&) [39], char const (&) [38]>(char const (&) [39], char const (&) [38]) ()
   from /lib64/libtensorflow_cc.so.2
#3  0x00007fffea3d0f7d in _GLOBAL__sub_I_context.cc () from /lib64/libtensorflow_cc.so.2
#4  0x00007ffff7dea9b3 in _dl_init_internal () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#5  0x00007ffff7ddc17a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x0000000000000002 in ?? ()
```

The flags from /proc/cpuinfo are

flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2
ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 f
ma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpc
id_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveop
t arat md_clear spec_ctrl intel_stibp arch_capabilities

Can anyone help me out in understanding the issue in this?

Comment: hi abhay can you run objdump on the binary `objdump -M intel -S [binary] | grep -i mm`. This is to cross check if there calls to avx-512

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did "objdump -M intel -S /usr/lib64/libtensorflow.so.2 | grep -i mm" but the output is really big for me to paste here.

Comment: can you just check if there are avx512 `objdump -M intel -S /usr/lib64/libtensorflow.so.2 | grep -i zmm` in `nsync::nsync_mu_init`? or can you dump the instructions for `nsync::nsync_mu_init` and cross `p $pc` to identify the instructions (or use list).

Comment: are there any updates if there are zmm register used in nsync_mu_init ? were you able to run in gdb and identify the instruction which caused the issue?

Comment: the CPU flags does not list any `avx512*`, there are no `p $PC`and `lsit`executed in GDB to identify what instruction caused `illegal instruction`, Can you share the information.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Thanks for being active on this. The CPU platform of the machine was Intel Broadwell, and as you said it doesn't have avx512* flag. We swapped the machine with Intel Cascade Lake platform and the crash is gone now.

Comment: Broadwell does not house avx512 that is zmm register. Hence have requested to check the instruction and init function. Good to hear the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tensor Flow heavily uses AVX instruction on x86 platforms. If the binary is compiled with AVX512 that is `zmm` registers the binary can run on supporting hardware. Hence as per the comments requested to check the instruction set via

1. `objdump -M intel -S /usr/lib64/libtensorflow.so.2 | grep -i zmm` and
2. `print $pc` in GDB to isloate the instruction.

Note: as per the update changing from Broadwell (no AVX512) to Skylake (AVX512) has solved the issue.